# Red Gate's SQL Toolbelt or Quest's Toad for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, toad

We are evaluating trial versions of Red Gate’s SQL Toolbelt and Quest Software’s Toad for SQL Server. What are the main differences between these tools? The benefits of using these tools are quite obvious but we are wondering which one is more suitable for a developer and development work? Is Toad for SQL Server more focused on DBA work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toad for SQL Sever basically is an alternative to SQL Server Management Studio - it gives you insights into your server, databases, database object etc. and you can execute queries and explore your data. But that's about it.

Red-Gate's Toolbelt is a totally different set of tools - a toolbelt, as the name implies:

- compare databases for structural or data-related differences
- determine dependencies between database objects
- greatly superior intellisense for SSMS and Visual Studio
- package database changes into an update package (EXE or .NET assembly)
- and a lot more

I don't think TOAD offers any of those capabilities, so you're really comparing apples to carrot or something here.

I can totally recommend Red Gate tools - I'm using SQL Prompt, SQL Search, SQL Compare, SQL Data Compare and SQL Packager regularly, and they just do their job in a great way. Highly recommended!

Answer (score 4):

The tools from RedGate are spectacular.  I don't know about Quest's Toad, but you cannot go wrong with RedGate.  In fact I often end up using their products as fodder for requirements on new features for my unrelated products.

They quickly respond to questions, provide intelligent assistance, and, well, if I could marry Redgate I would get down on one knee right now.

'nuff said?

Comment: This covers my impression with other products as well. Support is AAA and that is what realy counts at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Toad, has a free "community version" 6, which indeed offers intellisense, dependencies and other things.
There are 3 levels of paying versions and they have comparison tools + many extras which I could not evaluate since I am only using the free version.
Anyway, since I started using Toad I nearly never go back to SSMS...except for the free RedGate SQL Search, which is a real time saver in some situations.